# Get number of clicked page in DataPager control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datapager

I have a `Listview` and a `DataPager` control on my page and I'm trying to create a custom paging (listview shows only interval of results). When user clicks on any page, `DataPager_PreRender()` event fires which contains my datasource/databind method.

Please tell me how to get the number of page that was clicked in datapager to use it in the `PreRender` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender,PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)    
{

    int CurrentPage = (e.StartRowIndex / e.MaximumRows)+1;
    Response.Write(CurrentPage.ToString());

}
```

http://forums.asp.net/p/1391359/2974778.aspx

Hope this helps.